# how to download file in given path in onFileMessageReceived by using agora sdk in android

Tags: android, agora.io

**code at receiver end**

```
   @Override
                    public void onFileMessageReceivedFromPeer(RtmFileMessage rtmFileMessage, String s) {
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            if (s.equals(toProfID)) {
                                // String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + rtmFileMessage.getFileName();
                                final String cacheFile = getCacheFile(context, rtmFileMessage.getFileName());
                                Log.d("onFileMessageReceived", cacheFile);
                                RtmRequestId requestId = new RtmRequestId();
                                mRtmClient.downloadMediaToFile(
                                        rtmFileMessage.getMediaId(),
                                        cacheFile,
                                        requestId,
                                        new ResultCallback<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                                massageList.add(0,new ChatItem(ChatItem.LayoutSix, "", rtmFileMessage.getFileName(), cacheFile, Time(), false));
                                                chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                                recyclerView_list.scrollToPosition(0);

                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onFailure(ErrorInfo errorInfo) {
                                                Log.d("onFailure", "onFileMessageReceived" + errorInfo.toString());

                                            }
                                        }
                                );

                            }

                        });


                    }
```

**path as below**

```
  public static String getCacheFile(Context context, String id) {
    File parent = new File(context.getCacheDir(), CACHE_DIR);
    if (!parent.exists()) {
        parent.mkdirs();
    }

    return new File(parent, id).getAbsolutePath();
}
```

*unable to download this file from media id*

**want to download recived document. i am opening this document with respect formate . .pdf is openinig but actualy file is not open. i dont know issue **

Answer (score 0):

**use this code for download**

```
   public static String getCacheFile(Context context, String id) {
    File parent = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),
            "YourAppDirectory");
    if (!parent.exists()) {
        parent.mkdirs();
    }

    return new File(parent, id).getAbsolutePath();
}
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).